# Dotenv not getting value as string

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webpack, dotenv

I have installed dotenv to set enviroment variables for development and production, one of those variable is the `ROOT_API`, my env file look like this

```
NODE_ENV=dev
ROOT_API=http://localhost/project/public/
PORT=8000
```

I set my api request configuration in axios and followed the steps in the dotenv repo like this

```
require('dotenv').config({path: `${__dirname}/../.env`})
//I asume this is right as the value get returned 
//but there does not say that i have to configure anything else
export const http = axios.create({
  baseURL: process.env.ROOT_API + 'api/',
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Accept': 'application/json',
    'Authorization': tokenType + ' ' + token
  }
})
```

I expect that `process.env.ROOT_API` return the value as a string but in the console i see the error `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :` when i see where is the problem the values is shown as

```
var http = __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_5_axios___default.a.create({
  baseURL: http://localhost/project/public/ + 'api/',
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Accept': 'application/json',
    'Authorization': tokenType + ' ' + token
  }
});
```

i have tried

- using different quotes in the `.env` file
- convert the `process.env.ROOT_API` to string or logging the type of the value but get erro `SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list` as the value seems like plain text in js.
- using template literals like this `${process.env.ROOT_API}`; show in `console > sources` `'' + http://localhost/project/public/;` 
  //i dont know how to show the ` quotes it display it like code sorry.

I do a `console.log` to see what `process.env` have in console and this is what it shows

```
   ...
   PWD: 'C:/xampp/htdocs/project',
   ROOT_API: 'http://localhost/erp-api/public/',
   SESSIONNAME: 'Console',
   ...
```

how can i fix this? i do not understand why it not get the value as a string?

Comment: How are you loading dotEnv config in the code?

Comment: Edited, i just followed the repo steps.

Comment: have you tried template literal including wrap quotes?

    `baseURL: \`'${process.env.ROOT_API}api/'\``

Comment: yes i have, same result

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue and this is what I have done:

If you are using `webpack.DefinePlugin()` use `webpack.EnvironmentPlugin()` instead, and get the `dotenv.parsed` keys in there with `Object.keys()` like this:

```js
// webpack.config.js

const webpack = require('webpack')
const dotenv = require('dotenv').config()

module.exports = {

//...other configs

  plugins: [
     new webpack.EnvironmentPlugin(Object.keys(dotenv.parsed || {})),
  ]
]
```

Comment: Fixed the issue for me.  I was using this tutorial when I ran into problems. https://dev.to/sanfra1407/how-to-use-env-file-in-javascript-applications-with-webpack-18df

Answer (score 2):

Your code should run fine. I see no issue with it and I just validated it without webpack.

If

`baseURL: process.env.ROOT_API + 'api/'`

gets translated like:

`baseURL: http://localhost/project/public/ + 'api/',` it means that there is an issue with your transpilation. You should check for the issue there (or update the question with more info about your webpack config and usage)

Answer (score 2):

A bit late... but follows my solution.

```js
  ...
  plugins: [
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
    'process.env': JSON.stringify(dotenv.parsed)
  })
```

Converts everything to string no more random errors ;)

Answer (score 1):

Install this package as a development dependency (https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv-webpack):

```
npm install  --dev  dotenv-webpack
```

or

```
yarn add -D dotenv-webpack
```

After it, just add this code to your webpack file:

```
     const Dotenv = require('dotenv-webpack');

        module.exports = {
          ...
          plugins: [
            new Dotenv()
          ]
          ...
        };
```

Reference Link: https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv-webpack

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.